# How to trigger 3DSecure with PaymentIntent on Xamarin.iOs?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, stripe-payments

I've setup payment with Stripe.net on Xamarin iOs.
I collect Card datas and use a PaymentIntent to confirm the payment.
(the PaymentIntent is created by the server, I just confirm it).

It's working fine except when I use a 3DSecure card. 
I'm supposed to get a url to open so that the user can perform the 3DSecure check, but all I get in next_action is a blank url.

---

EDIT : see taintedzodiac answer below :

Adding a return_url parameter to the PaymentIntent changes it to manual authentication mode, which allow us to get the url in the next_action object

It's a good enough answer for now, but it would be better to have a view that automatically trigger the 3DSecure popup if needed, like in iOs.

---

Is there another way to perform the payment that would automatically trigger the 3DSecure popup in xamarin.ios ?

Here is how I create the paymentIntent :

```
PaymentIntentConfirmOptions optionsConfirm = new PaymentIntentConfirmOptions
                    {
                        PaymentMethodId = _paymentMethod.Id,
                        ClientSecret = intentSecret.client_secret
                    };

                    PaymentIntentService paymentIntentService = new PaymentIntentService();
                    PaymentIntent intent = paymentIntentService.Confirm(intentSecret.id, optionsConfirm);
```

The intent returns the following object :

```
{<Stripe.PaymentIntent@782394758 id=pi_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX> JSON: {
  "id": "pi_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "object": "payment_intent",
  "amount": 5000,
  "amount_capturable": null,
  "amount_received": null,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee_amount": null,
  "canceled_at": null,
  "cancellation_reason": null,
  "capture_method": "automatic",
  "charges": null,
  "client_secret": "pi_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "confirmation_method": "automatic",
  "created": 1567605523,
  "currency": "eur",
  "customer": null,
  "description": null,
  "invoice": null,
  "last_payment_error": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": null,
  "next_action": {
    "redirect_to_url": null,
    "type": "use_stripe_sdk"
  },
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "payment_method": "pm_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "payment_method_options": null,
  "payment_method_types": [
    "card"
  ],
  "receipt_email": null,
  "review": null,
  "setup_future_usage": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "source": null,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
  "status": "requires_action",
  "transfer_data": null,
  "transfer_group": null,
  "allowed_source_types": null
}}
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see `"next_action": { "type": "use_stripe_sdk" }` you can expect that there will be a `null` value for the `redirect_to_url` field. The `type` value of `"use_stripe_sdk"` is telling you that you should [use Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents#see-how-it-works) rather than needing to redirect to another URL for authentication.

You will only see a value for `redirect_to_url` if you are [handling authentication manually](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/verifying-status#manual-3ds-auth).

Comment: Hey @taintedzodiac, thanks for your answer. 
The link helped me to find a solution :
You have to provide a return_url to your paymentIntent if you want to handle the authentication manually, then you will receive an url to open in the next_action object